# How to block ScrollViewer Gesture if I touch some specific part in this ScrollViewer?

Tags: windows-phone-8, gesture, scrollviewer

In my **windows phone app**,I have a need to do that:
I put a map in a scroll viewer,
if I touch the map,the map work,doesn't result in scroll viewer moving
if I touch the position outside the map but in the scroll viewer,the scroll viewer scrolls.
**Here is my xaml layout:**

```
<ScrollViewer Height="800">
    <Grid Height="400" x:Name="ContentPanel"  Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <myMap/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**I have these gesture control blew about the map:**

```
    myMap.ManipulationStarted += OnManipulationStarted;
    myMap.ManipulationDelta += OnManipulationDelta;
    myMap.ManipulationCompleted += OnManipulationCompleted;
```

**each of the OnManipulation have a "e.Handled=true"**
but doesn't work
Please help me if you have any advice,Thanks!

---

Update

if the layout is

```
    <phone:Panorama Grid.Row="1">
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="First">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <!--ContentPanel - 在此处放置其他内容-->
                <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Height="400" Margin="12,0,12,0">

                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Second">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello world"/>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama
```

then myMap can't work completely,**how to solve the gesture conflict problem**?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @Alexander yes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.manipulationmode(v=vs.95).aspx set ManipulationMode="Control" to your scrollviewer

Answer (score 1):

set **ManipulationMode="Control"** in your scrollviewer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.manipulationmode(v=vs.95).aspx